Tourist visa for more than 3 months
I’ve been seen so many people talking about the USA tourist visa with duration of 6 months, how can you get it?
My mother has been traveling to the USA as a tourist for about 11 years and the maximum she always gets is 3 months…

Can I know your mother's nationality? AFAIK, US issues 10 year visas by default and each entry is stamped for usually 6 months.

US applies reciprocity rule. If your mother country restrict validity of visa to US citizens, US will do the same.

If your mother is from a Visa Waiver Program country (I.e. she uses an ESTA and not an actual visa) then the limit is indeed 90 days per trip. A standard visitor visa allows for 6 months per trip in the vast majority of cases.

@GiacomoCatenazzi: Right, but reciprocity only affects the length of visa validity, not the length of stay (which is what it sounds like this question is talking about). Even if you had a visitor visa valid for 1 day, they would admit you for 6 months.

@DianaDuarte: Is your mother entering on an actual B2 visa? Or is she entering on the Visa Waiver Program? A US visa is a sticker that takes up an entire page of the passport and says "VISA" on it. You can only get a US visa at a US consulate.

My mother is Portuguese. And yes, she’s entering with an ESTA which now I understand is not an actual visa. I thought that it was actually the same as a tourist visa. Thank you for the clarications.
